# What are AUTHOR_WARNING messages in cmake?

Tags: cmake

CMake's `message()` directive has an `AUTHOR_WARNING` mode, however [the documentation (v3.11.1)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/message.html) doesn't say anything on what the differences are between an `AUTHOR_WARNING` and a regular `WARNING`.

The documentation states these modes and their description as follows:

```
WARNING        = CMake Warning, continue processing
AUTHOR_WARNING = CMake Warning (dev), continue processing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author warning are meant to warn the author (developer) of a CMakeLists.txt, but not a user of it. With the CMake arguments `-Wdev`, `-Wno-dev`, and `-Werror=dev` you have control over how to these warnings are handled ([documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html)).

The idea is that users should not be scared or annoyed by warnings they cannot change anyway, because they are not supposed to modify this part (of potentially third-party) code.  This includes programmers who include CMake code from others and don't want to warned about issues they cannot fix within their code.

Since CMake 3.5, the `dev` flags also [suppress or enable deprecation warnings](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.5.html#command-line), following the spirit of warning only people who can fix the underlying issues.